# chef-client displays too much output when copying binary file

Tags: chef-infra

I'm testing a chef recipe on a local docker machine using chef-client in local mode. One file I copy via `template` is a self-extracting shell script. Problem is that chef tries to print the diff between this file and the existing file, which results in a lot of gibberish being sent to the screen. I'm hoping someone has a workaround.

I tried setting `sensitive true` on the file, but that didn't seem to have an effect. I could put the file on the web and download it from there, but I was hoping for something better. Like a quiet mode or something.

Update #1

Here is the relevant code from recipes/default.rb

```
template '/file.sh' do
  source 'file.sh'
end
```

Comment: Really? `sensitive true` does not hide the output? You might lower the threshold, until which a diff is emitted using [diff_output_threshold](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/aa9bbabde662a58c581ed4d87707eac5534bc292/lib/chef/util/diff.rb#L131), but we should try to figure out what's wrong with your `sensitive` setting. Please add your code!

Comment: I found out that the output in question was errors from the template engine, not a diff printing out from the chef client. In this case, apparently `sensitive true` doesn't suppress output.

Comment: How do you call the template engine? Using the `execute` resource? Then add `sensitive true` for that one, too..

Comment: I added the code block from my recipe. Changing it to cookbook_file did what I wanted. It seems like binary files are best served as cookbook_file anyways.

Comment: Exactly, erubis does not deal well with binaries. Next time, please add your code and error output. Otherwise we can't follow you.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question...

The core problem was that I was using a template to create a file that had binary data in it (it's a self extracting shell script) and the template engine was dumping errors to the screen, e.g., "warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space" Some errors included binary strings and escape characters.

The right answer for me was to make this a cookbook_file instead of a template.